# short links with htaccess - two arguments

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got little problem that I am not sure how to fix. I am using htaccess file to rewrite my url to shorter links. For example I am using this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^client/(.*)/?$ pages/client.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

but I wanted to also pass second argument to that URL so I made this:

```
RewriteRule ^client/(.*)/(.*)/?$ pages/client.php?action=$1&view=$2 [L,QSA]
```

so I could access URL like:

```
/client/action_1/view_2
```

without any problems but when I skipped second argument and only accessed:

```
/client/action_1/
```

then it was impossilbe and resulted in 404.

How to make a change to that RewriteRule so I can access both:

```
/client/action_1/view_2
/client/action_1/
```

and it would rewrite to:

```
pages/client.php?action=$1&view=$2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have 2 separate rules to handle 2 clean URLs:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^client/([^/]+)/?$ pages/client.php?action=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^client/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ pages/client.php?action=$1&view=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: There was a typo, it is fixed now. Please test again.

Comment: I gave you plus 1 for the answer but someone downgraded before your reply so now it's [0]. I am sorry for that but it was not me. Anyway, thank you again!

Comment: Yes I know it wasn't you. It was from someone who didn't understand the solution. I am seeing many downvotes on my answers without any explanation actually. btw I upvoted your question too.